# Como lidar com erros em arquitetura hexagonal (ports and adapters)

Tags: java, arquitetura-de-software

Bom, venho estudando o padrão de design Ports and Adapters e a princípio parece ser bem interessante, porém, surgiram dúvidas.

**Contexto**

Toda aplicação lida com cenários de erros, seja um bug ou uma exception própria. Fazemos isso lançando e capturando com um bloco de try/catch.

No padrão Ports and Adapters, isolamos o application core dos frameworks que o projeto venha a ter, através de portas inbound e outbound que ficam dentro da application e servem de entrada/saída para o mundo externo através de implementações concretas, os adapters.

É relativamente simples estruturar isso de forma que atenda ao padrão, mas ao entrar no tratamento de erro a coisa fica um pouco mais complicada.

**Exemplo**

Digamos que eu esteja trabalhando com uma aplicação de propostas de seguro. Para simplificar há o caso de uso *UpdateProposal*, que dado uma proposta já existente, ele deve atualizar o registro em uma base de dados e publicar uma mensagem em uma fila SQS, por exemplo. E digamos que como entrada dessa aplicação temos uma Web API Rest e um consumidor que consome as mensagens de outra fila.

Então temos dois adapters inbound: *ProposalSqsConsumer*, *ProposalController*;

Dois adapters outbound: *ProposalDynamoDb*, *ProposalSqsPublisher*;

Uma porta inbound: *ProposalUpdatePort*;

Duas portas outbound: *ProposalRepository*, *ProposalPublisher*;

E uma UseCase que implementa o *ProposalUpdatePort*, e chama as duas portas outbound que são implementadas pelo *ProposalDynamoDb* e *ProposalSqsPublisher*. Então, os dois adapters usam a mesma UseCase através de *ProposalUpdatePort*.

**Problemática**

Digamos que na hora que a UseCase chama a outbound port de persistência, o adapter do Dynamo lança uma exceção de *EntityNotFoundException*. Quem deve tratar essa exceção e qual a melhor forma de fazer isso no padrão Ports and adapters? Exemplos:

1° A porta outbound *ProposalRepository* coloca junto do contrato do método *update()* um *throws EntityNotFoundException* (ou especificando todas as exceções), indicando para a UseCase que pode haver essa(s) exceção(ões) e dizendo para que qualquer adapter de persistência que for implementar essa porta para que respeite esse contrato, lançando apenas exceções que a UseCase conhece. E ela faz alguma lógica ou nehuma, simplesmente lançando pro adapter a exceção. Tendo de especificar na porta inbound *ProposalUpdatePort* no método *update()* também o *throws EntityNotFoundException*, para que os dois adapters possam se virar para tratar. No caso do Controller ele pode retornar como um 404 e no caso do Consumer ele propaga novamente a exceção para a mensagem retornar para a fila.

2° É definido na porta outbound de persistência no método *update()* o *throws EntityNotFoundException* ou todas as possíveis exceções, mas a UseCase não captura nada via try/catch, simplesmente deixando propagar para a camada dos adapters, tendo de também especificar as exceções na porta inbound *ProposalUpdatePort*, para que os adapters não seja pegos de "surpresa". Então a cláusula *throws* da porta inbound sempre vai ser a soma das exceções lançadas pelas portas outbounds que são usadas naquela UseCase ou serviço. Mas isso me parece um tanto estranho.

Pensando nisso tudo, qual seria a melhor abordagem para tratamento de erros em uma arquitetura hexagonal?